# Mootools 1.3 & JSON Access values in json array with Request.JSON and insert HTML into DOM from json data

Tags: javascript, json, mootools

I have a request.json in mootools to get some data from a php function returning the following:

```
{"userID":"1",
 "userName":"Ezra",
 "total":5,
 "listItems":[
 {"sessionID":"9",
 "sessionName":"tmimportertest100_(9-1_100)",
 "sessionCount":100,
 "sessionDC":"12:11AM - Jun 06 11",
 "sessionDM":"01:00AM - Jan 01 70",
 "sessionActive":"1"},
{"sessionID":"10",
 "sessionName":"tmimportertest100_(10-1_100)",
 "sessionCount":100,
 "sessionDC":"05:04PM - Jun 06 11",
 "sessionDM":"01:00AM - Jan 01 70",
 "sessionActive":"1"}]}
```

I need to setup a loop to insert a listItem into a div for each "set" of data from "sessionID" to "sessionActive".

```
var req = new Request.JSON(
{
url: 'ajax.php?action=getSessions',
onSuccess: function(session)
{
    // ????
}
}).send();
```

the info on the Mootools website is a lil confusing on this stuff, I know basicly howto inject elements and create them.. but accessing the json and creating a for loop around it.. #confused#

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access the json data as a normal javascript object.

```
onSuccess: function(jsonData){
    var container = document.id('container');
    var items = jsonData.listItems;
    Array.each(items, function(row){
        new Element('div').adopt(
            new Element('h1', {text:row.sessionName}),
            new Element('h2.count', {text:row.sessionCount})
        ).inject(container);
    });
}
```